# How do I find how many times a value has been repeated in a column - R

Tags: r, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count unique values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215154/count-unique-values-in-r)

I have just one column full of names, and I need to know how many times each name is on this column.

I can do a

```
summary(dfUL)
```

where dfUL is my user list data frame

This will give me a summary with the number of times a particular value is repeated, but it will only do it for the top 6. How can i do that for the entire data frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try already `table(dfUL)`?

Comment: No I hadn't, yes this solves it...i feel really bad for asking such a stupid questions. Thanks.

Comment: @vonHippie  "there are no stupid questions, just stupid answers."   PS remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibly useful method would be the `match()` function.

```
match(x,dfUL$somecol) #Where x is the value in somecol you are looking for
match(max(dfUL$somecol),dfUL) #Returns the row with the maximum value of somecol
```