# R create possible combinations of variables

Tags: r

I have a list as follows:

```
mylist <- list(A=seq_len(3)-1, A=seq_len(3)-1, B=seq_len(2)-1, B=seq_len(2)-1)

mylist

$A
[1] 0 1 2

$A
[1] 0 1 2

$B
[1] 0 1

$B
[1] 0 1
```

meaning that two instances of `A` can have the state 0,1,2 and two instances of `B` can have the state 0,1.

I would like to produce strings with products of all combinations of all instances, for which the sum of states is (as an example) 1.

I do this by first getting all possible combinations for both `A`'s and `B's` and taking the subset for which the sum is 1.

```
all.combns <- expand.grid(mylist)
ac <- all.combns[which(rowSums(all.combns)==1),]
unname(apply(ac, 1, function(x)paste(colnames(ac), x, sep="_", collapse=" * ")))
```

Result is:

```
"A_1 * A_0 * B_0 * B_0" 
"A_0 * A_1 * B_0 * B_0" 
"A_0 * A_0 * B_1 * B_0"
"A_0 * A_0 * B_0 * B_1"
```

First and second string and third and fourth string are he same.
My desired result would be:

```
"2 * A_1 * A_0 * B_0 * B_0" 
"2 * A_0 * A_0 * B_1 * B_0"
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? I thought about adding the rows for both `A`'s and `B`'s in `all.combns` e.g. `cbind(all.combns[,1]+all.combns[,2], all.combns[,3]+all.combns[,3])` and then counting the unique elements with methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215154/count-unique-values-in-r). However, I do think there must be an easier solution to this, without forming all combinations with `expand.grid`.

Comment: @user1987175 -- In regards to your reviewing, this answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3871248#./3871248?&_suid=139040787868004590174438491092) is obviously not an answer; please be more careful when reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. But I guess there is room for more conciseness. I changed your `paste` step so the results will be sorted before creating the string as order does not seem to matter in your case. Then use `ddply` to count identical cases.

```
ac <- cmbs[rowSums(cmbs) == 1,]
a <- data.frame(v=apply(ac, 1, function(x) 
  paste(sort(paste(colnames(ac), x, sep="_")), collapse=" * ")))
d <- ddply(a, .(v), summarise, new = paste(length(v), "*", unique(v))) 
d[, "new"]

"2 * A_0 * A_0 * B_0 * B_1" "2 * A_0 * A_1 * B_0 * B_0"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution with `plyr`. It works fine for this example, however, I am still thinking of how to avoid using `expand.grid` to calculate all combinations, since in my real application, I have a list with six instances of `A` with values 0 to 4 and six of `B` from 0 to to, which makes  5^6 * 3^6 = 11390625 combinations