# How to count how many values per level in a given factor?

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a data.frame `mydf` with about 2500 rows. These rows correspond to 69 classes of objects in colum 1 `mydf$V1`, and I want to count how many rows per object class I have.
I can get a factor of these classes with:

```
objectclasses = unique(factor(mydf$V1, exclude="1"));
```

What's the terse R way to count the rows per object class? If this were any other language I'd be traversing an array with a loop and keeping count but I'm new to R programming and am trying to take advantage of R's vectorised operations.

Comment: Have you tried a `table`?  Without a reproducible example it's hard to guess the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215154/count-unique-values-in-r/4215196#4215196

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Or using the `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE))
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(ID))
```

Note the use of `%>%`, which is similar to the use of pipes in bash. Effectively, the code above pipes `dat` into `group_by`, and the result of that operation is piped into `summarise`.

The result is:

```
Source: local data frame [26 x 2]

   ID no_rows
1   a       2
2   b       3
3   c       3
4   d       3
5   e       2
6   f       4
7   g       6
8   h       1
9   i       6
10  j       5
11  k       6
12  l       4
13  m       7
14  n       2
15  o       2
16  p       2
17  q       5
18  r       4
19  s       5
20  t       3
21  u       8
22  v       4
23  w       5
24  x       4
25  y       3
26  z       1
```

See the [`dplyr` introduction](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) for some more context, and the documentation for details regarding the individual functions.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. The table answer is also useful; there are a few problems with the data that prevent me using a table for the moment, so I am using a data.frame for the moment.

Comment: I'm new to R, but it seems this dplyr package is the jquery of R.  It's the answer for a LOT of things.

Comment: Using `table` instead would be better, as it doesn't require an extra library.

Comment: @YanFoto I fail to see why limiting yourself to base R is preferable. By this logic you would favor using the base graphics over ggplot2, where ggplot2 is imo a lot better. I can imagine situations where your argument could hold (for example when for some reason you cannot install extra packages, or are stuck with an old version of R that does not support a particular package). However, as a blanket statement I do not agree that base R solutions are better than those using additional packages.

Comment: `ggplot2` actually provides an added value over `graphics`, whereas in this case the provided solution does exactly the same as what `table` would do for a factor. My comment refers the problem and the question at hand and *is* not a general statement regarding packages.

Comment: I think dplyr has merit over table, especially if you consider the wider context of what dplyr can do.

Comment: I am on the same page with you on what `deplyr` can do. I think the misunderstanding is coming from my statement. I don't acclaim universality! I meant that as an opinion limited within the context of this question. Given a factor `f`, `table(f)` does the same thing as this solution suggests.

Comment: @YanFoto I also feel for your argument, but even in this case I would not prefer table over dplyr. For me, using dplyr is default, using base R is the exception. Also note that these kind of comments are not the ideal way to get across a balanced point :).

Answer (score 41):

Here 2 ways to do it:

```
set.seed(1)
tt <- sample(letters,100,rep=TRUE)

## using table
table(tt)
tt
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
2 3 3 3 2 4 6 1 6 5 6 4 7 2 2 2 5 4 5 3 8 4 5 4 3 1 
## using tapply
tapply(tt,tt,length)
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
2 3 3 3 2 4 6 1 6 5 6 4 7 2 2 2 5 4 5 3 8 4 5 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 34):

Using `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)

count(mydf$V1)
```

It will return you a frequency of each value.

Comment: This is the easiest method I can see here, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! it returns a list.

Answer (score 25):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, .N, keyby=ID] #(Using @Paul Hiemstra's `dat`)
```

Or using `dplyr 0.3`

```
 res <- count(dat, ID)
 head(res)
 #Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

 #  ID n
 #1  a 2
 #2  b 3
 #3  c 3
 #4  d 3
 #5  e 2
 #6  f 4
```

Or

```
  dat %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      tally()
```

Or

```
  dat %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(n=n())
```

Answer (score 17):

We can use `summary` on factor column:

```
summary(myDF$factorColumn)
```

Comment: `summary(ggplot2::diamonds$clarity)` looks like it performed as desired.

Comment: This should be accepted as a solution, it is done via one built-in function and outputs exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 6):

One more  approach would be to  apply n() function which is counting the number of  observations

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data %>% 
  group_by(columnName) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
```

Answer (score 3):

In case I just want to know how many unique factor levels exist in the data, I use:

```
length(unique(df$factorcolumn))
```

Comment: this doesn't yield the number of values per level

Answer (score 1):

Use the package plyr with lapply to get frequencies for every value (level) and every variable (factor) in your data frame.

```
library(plyr)
lapply(df, count)
```

Comment: this answer likely belongs as a comment. please review how to write a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but you can do this with base R and no data frames/data tables:

```
sapply(levels(yTrain), function(sLevel) sum(yTrain == sLevel))
```