# R Count number of times a level occurs in n rows

Tags: r

I have, for example, a vector with 1000 obs and 3 levels (A, B, C). I want to count how many times level A occurs for every 5 rows and produce another vector of the count values, ie with 200obs. Is anyone able to help? I've found how to count based on another variable but not number of rows. Thank you!

```
df <- data.frame(test=factor(sample(c("A","B", "C" ),1000,replace=TRUE)))
head(df, 10)
   test
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     C
5     B
6     A
7     C
8     B
9     C
10    C
```

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(split(df$test, rep(1:200, each = 5)), table)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - how to count how many values per level in a given factor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114525/r-how-to-count-how-many-values-per-level-in-a-given-factor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options you might find useful:

a) count all entries per 5 rows and return a list:

```
head(lapply(split(df$test, rep(1:200, each = 5)), table), 2)
# $`1`      # <- result for rows 1:5
# 
# A B C 
# 1 0 4 
# 
# $`2`      # <- result for rows 6:10
# 
# A B C 
# 3 0 2
```

b) count all entries per 5 rows and return a matrix:

```
head(t(sapply(split(df$test, rep(1:200, each = 5)), table)), 2)
#   A B C
# 1 1 0 4
# 2 3 0 2
```

c) count number of `A`s per 5 rows and return a list:

```
head(lapply(split(df$test == "A", rep(1:200, each = 5)), sum), 2)
# $`1`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 3
```

d) count number of `A`s per 5 rows and return a vector:

```
head(sapply(split(df$test == "A", rep(1:200, each = 5)), sum), 2)
#1 2 
#1 3
```

Each of the results will be 200 entries long / have 200 rows.

Comment: Instead of `rep(1:200, each = 5)` you could also use something like `((seq_len(nrow(df)) -1) %/% 5) +1`

Comment: An alternative to `split`ting could be `table(rep(seq_len(nrow(df) / 5), each = 5), df$test)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Set = (seq_along(test) - 1) %/% 5) %>%
  group_by(Set, test) %>%
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  spread(key = test, value = N, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N , .(grp= gl(nrow(df), 5, nrow(df)), test)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `dplyr`, you could use

```
  c1 <- df %>%
  mutate(group = rep(paste0("G", seq(1, 200)), each = 5)) %>%
  # count each level
  count(group, test)
```

Note that this method doesn't include levels with no values for a certain group (i.e. no 0 values)