# Calculate the most consumed food items by Ill Patients

Tags: r, data-science, analysis, eda

I have a dataset as below, which has many columns. There are some columns whose headings are :

```
baked_hamburgur,spinach,mashed_potato,cabbages,jello,rolls,brown,milk,coffee,water,cakes,vanilla,chocolate,fruitsalad
```

There are other columns as well, but I am only interested as of now in the above columns.

the value in each row of these columns is either: yes, or no.

A screenshot of this data is as under, as I am not able to attach/share this file in the question itself.

[image: My Dataset with many columns for Data Analysis of Ill Patients]

The dput(head()) output is as under:

```
> dput(head(illness_data))

structure(list(Age = structure(c(18L, 26L, 22L, 25L, 29L, 13L
), .Label = c("10", "106", "11", "12", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "2", "20", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "36", "38", "39", "4", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "48", "5", "7", "8", "9", "seven"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("-1", 
    "Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), timesupper = c(2000L, 
    1830L, 1830L, 1930L, 1930L, 1930L), ill = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), onsetdate = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("18-Apr", "18-Jun", "18/4", 
    "19-Apr"), class = "factor"), onsettime = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 
    2230L, 2230L, 200L), baked_hamburgur = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    spinach = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), mashed_potato = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    cabbages = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), jello = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    rolls = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), brown = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    milk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), coffee = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    water = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), cakes = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    vanilla = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), chocolate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    fruitsalad = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes", "yes</pre></body></html>Ztext/plain\b\v\035(F]l~Ó_Ý\026R\002\001"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Age", "sex", "timesupper", 
"ill", "onsetdate", "onsettime", "baked_hamburgur", "spinach", 
"mashed_potato", "cabbages", "jello", "rolls", "brown", "milk", 
"coffee", "water", "cakes", "vanilla", "chocolate", "fruitsalad"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

A complete dput command output is as under:

```
> dput(illness_data)

structure(list(Age = structure(c(18L, 26L, 22L, 25L, 29L, 13L, 
36L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 24L, 10L, 8L, 35L, 34L, 6L, 22L, 39L, 12L, 
9L, 36L, 17L, 9L, 20L, 37L, 27L, 32L, 30L, 21L, 24L, 3L, 18L, 
33L, 16L, 5L, 31L, 28L, 14L, 19L, 38L, 2L, 4L, 23L, 1L, 18L, 
15L), .Label = c("10", "106", "11", "12", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "2", "20", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "36", "38", "39", "4", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "48", "5", "7", "8", "9", "seven"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("-1", "Female", "Male"
    ), class = "factor"), timesupper = c(2000L, 1830L, 1830L, 
    1930L, 1930L, 1930L, 2200L, 1900L, 1930L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2200L, NA, NA, NA, 2200L, NA, NA, 2200L, 2200L, NA, NA, 2200L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1900L, NA, 1100L, NA, NA, NA, 2200L, 
    1930L, 1930L, 2200L, NA, NA, 1930L, 1930L, NA, NA), ill = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), onsetdate = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("18-Apr", "18-Jun", "18/4", "19-Apr"), class = "factor"), 
    onsettime = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 2230L, 2230L, 200L, 100L, 2300L, 
    200L, 1030L, 30L, 2215L, 2200L, 100L, 2300L, 2145L, 2145L, 
    100L, 2300L, 2100L, 100L, 100L, 2115L, 2330L, 100L, 2130L, 
    230L, 200L, 2130L, 30L, 100L, 2230L, 1500L, 2400L, 2300L, 
    2230L, 100L, 230L, 2330L, 100L, 30L, 30L, 100L, 2400L, 215L, 
    2300L), baked_hamburgur = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), spinach = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), mashed_potato = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), cabbages = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), jello = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), rolls = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), brown = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), milk = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), coffee = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), water = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), cakes = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), vanilla = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), chocolate = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), fruitsalad = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("no", "yes", "yes</pre></body></html>Ztext/plain\b\v\035(F]l~Ó_Ý\026R\002\001"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Age", "sex", "timesupper", 
"ill", "onsetdate", "onsettime", "baked_hamburgur", "spinach", 
"mashed_potato", "cabbages", "jello", "rolls", "brown", "milk", 
"coffee", "water", "cakes", "vanilla", "chocolate", "fruitsalad"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -46L))
```

R has correctly read these columns as Factor type variable(s).

Now, each of these columns correspond to what every ill patient in a hospital has consumed.

I'd like to know the most consumed food item by ill patients, using R.

Kindly advise a good way to do so. Thanks!

Note, I have not tried any other options, than the ones mentioned in this URL below. However, I could not make it work.

[Count Factor Columns Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114525/how-to-count-how-many-values-per-level-in-a-given-factor)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: Also include what have you tried to code so far and how is it not working

Comment: Hello, @Andreas I have not tried any code so far other than what I found from this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114525/how-to-count-how-many-values-per-level-in-a-given-factor. However, none of the methods mentioned here works in my case. I have updated my question description as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the rows have `ill = 'yes'` we can count in each column the number of values with `yes` in it. A base R approach could be :

```
head(sort(colSums(illness_data[7:20] == "yes"), decreasing = TRUE), 5)

#        vanilla baked_hamburgur           cakes         spinach   mashed_potato 
#             43              29              27              26              23
```

I have selected columns 7 to 20 because those are the only columns where food item is present. Also I have selected only top 5 values, you can select any value by changing the number 5 in `head` command.

Comment: This is by far the most simplest and accurate answer! BTW, is there a way to represent the output as a dataframe and then plot it using plot() function in R?

Comment: @SuddhasatwaBhaumik yes, you can do `plot(stack(head(sort(colSums(illness_data[7:20] == "yes"), decreasing = TRUE), 5))[2:1])`

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you are looking for, but this will calculate how often foods  are consumed (using the `tidyverse` package):

```
library(tidyverse)
illness_data_summed <- illness_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Age, -sex, -timesupper,-onsetdate,-onsettime), ~ifelse(. == "yes", 1,0)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-Age, -sex, -timesupper,-onsetdate,-onsettime, -ill), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)) 

illness_data_summed[which(illness_data_summed == max(illness_data_summed))]
```

So first I convert the yes into 1 and no into 0, which makes the sum a representation of the number of times the specific food was eaten. I do it for all columns except those you are not interested in (indicated by the - in vars) but you can also reverse that if that is desirable (e.g., when the number of vars yo uwant to convert is lower than those you do not want to convert).

The last part will result in:

```
  vanilla
1      43
```