# Is there any way to replace for loops in r

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, for-loop

I have 2 [dataframes](/questions/tagged/dataframes). One with 4000(EPM_CODES) elements and other with 400000(df) elements.

I am trying to find out the number of occurrences of `EPM_CODE` in `df`. I have the following code which is working. But, taking 4 hours to complete. Is there a quicker way to accomplish this task?

Your help is appreciated.

Below is the code which I have:

```
for (EPM_CODE in EPM_Codes$`EPM Application Code`){
  COUNT_OF_OCCURENCES <- nrow(as.data.frame(df$ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES[grepl(paste0(",",EPM_CODE), df$ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES) | grepl(paste0('"',EPM_CODE), df$ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES) | grepl(paste0('_',EPM_CODE), df$ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTES) ]))
  result <- cbind(EPM_CODE,COUNT_OF_OCCURENCES)
  Final <- rbind(Final,result)
  #print(Final)
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: look into the `lapply` family of function. Particularly you can apply custom functions to lists as follows `lapply(data, function(X) )`

Comment: The problem is not with the for loop, but what you do inside it: https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/.

Answer (score 1):

**Data:**

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42734863/1691723

```
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}
set.seed(2L)
EPM_CODES <- myFun(4000)
df <- data.frame( x = sample(EPM_CODES, 400000, replace = TRUE))
```

**Code:**

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117442/1691723

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)[x %in% EPM_CODES, .N, keyby=x]

#             x   N
# 1: AADIP7357E 106
# 2: AAIQS2844S 101
# 3: AAMIJ4546E 104
# 4: AARRM3046V  98
# 5: AAVHW9261Y  94
# ---               
# 3996: ZZLCN5345R  82
# 3997: ZZUKM1348P  85
# 3998: ZZUOU5109E  99
# 3999: ZZUYE3207T  96
# 4000: ZZYEU6750J 115


system.time({ setDT(df)[x %in% EPM_CODES, .N, keyby=x] })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.09    0.00    0.09
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off @Sathish's answer, we can use joining in data.table to obviate the need to make a copy.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(EPM_CODES)
EPM_CODES[unique(EPM_CODES[,.(`EPM Application Code`)]),.N,on = 'EPM Application Code', by = 'EPM Application Code']
#      EPM Application Code   N
#   1:           XYTRN6637W 115
#   2:           VHNNR8661H  89
#   3:           KJSSN2069O  98
#  ---                         
#3998:           QQAHP4035A  96
#3999:           EHMBU6110N 114
#4000:           MAWLD3865R  94
```

Note the subtle difference between the ` and ' above.

Data from @Sathish.

```
set.seed(2L)
EPM_CODES <- myFun(4000)
EPM_CODES <- data.frame( x = sample(EPM_CODES, 400000, replace = TRUE))
setDT(EPM_CODES)
EPM_CODES[,Value := sample(1:5,nrow(EPM_CODES),replace = TRUE)]
setnames(EPM_CODES,"x","EPM Application Code")
```