# Count how many values per level in a given factor?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count, data-manipulation

For each year, I would like to create two new columns `temp_count` and `rh_count` counting the number of occurrences in each `temp_catog` and `humidity_catog` columns, respectively. This [How to count how many values per level in a given factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114525/how-to-count-how-many-values-per-level-in-a-given-factor?noredirect=1&lq=1) answers if you group by one variable, but I would like to use `group_by(year, humidity_catog, temp_catog)`. Here is a screenshot of my data

[image]

I can a create a single column `humidity_count` to count number of occurrences in each category `humidity_catog` column using the following code.

```
df <- group_by(year, humidity_catog) %>%
  summarize(humidity_count = n())
```

Here is the output

[image]

But I would like to create another column `temp_count` in the same data frame to count the number of each category `temp_count` column. How can I achieve this? Here is the reproducible example of my data created via dput function.

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    year = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
        1L, 1L, 1L),
      .Label = c(
        "2006",
        "2007",
        "2012",
        "2013",
        "2014",
        "2014_c",
        "2015_a",
        "2015_b",
        "2016",
        "2017",
        "2020"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    min_rh = c(47.9, 49, 44.7, 40.2, 50, 52.3, 51.5, 82.8, 73.8,
               47.1),
    min_temp = c(12.4, 14.3, 15.1, 16.1, 12.7, 16.1, 14.4,
                 15.1, 11.8, 9.5),
    temp_catog = structure(
      c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
        2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L),
      .Label = c("T1(<=8)", "T2(>8, <=15)",
                 "T3(>15)"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    humidity_catog = structure(
      c(1L,
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L),
      .Label = c("RH1(<=65)",
                 "RH2(>65)"),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      year = structure(
        1L,
        .Label = c(
          "2006",
          "2007",
          "2012",
          "2013",
          "2014",
          "2014_c",
          "2015_a",
          "2015_b",
          "2016",
          "2017",
          "2020"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1:10),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-1L),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

Note: I don't want unique occurrences. I just want to count how many times each category was recorded.

Comment: use `count(...)` function or `tally` or `group_by(...)%>%mutate(n=n())` etc

Comment: @onyambu It's factor variable - those wont' work. I can create two different df using `df1 <- group_by(year, humidity_catog) %>%
  summarize(humidity_count = n())` and `df2 <- group_by(year, temp_catog) %>%
  summarize(temp_count = n())` and then combine them but I want an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure how the OP means to merge the two summarised results, but we may call `mutate` instead of `summarise`, sequentially, feeding the grouping variables to the `.by` argument.

obs: the toy dataframe was grouped by year, I ungrouped it beforehand

```
library(dplyr) #requires dplyr 1.1.0 for the .by solution

df %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(rh_count = n(), .by = c(year, humidity_catog)) %>%
    mutate(temp_count = n(), .by = c(year, temp_catog))

# A tibble: 10 × 7
   year  min_rh min_temp temp_catog   humidity_catog rh_count temp_count
   <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>        <fct>             <int>      <int>
 1 2006    47.9     12.4 T2(>8, <=15) RH1(<=65)             8          6
 2 2006    49       14.3 T2(>8, <=15) RH1(<=65)             8          6
 3 2006    44.7     15.1 T3(>15)      RH1(<=65)             8          4
 4 2006    40.2     16.1 T3(>15)      RH1(<=65)             8          4
 5 2006    50       12.7 T2(>8, <=15) RH1(<=65)             8          6
 6 2006    52.3     16.1 T3(>15)      RH1(<=65)             8          4
 7 2006    51.5     14.4 T2(>8, <=15) RH1(<=65)             8          6
 8 2006    82.8     15.1 T3(>15)      RH2(>65)              2          4
 9 2006    73.8     11.8 T2(>8, <=15) RH2(>65)              2          6
10 2006    47.1      9.5 T2(>8, <=15) RH1(<=65)             8          6
```

Comment: Yes, joining df doesn't answer the question. Maybe it's not possible to get two summary statistics for counts. I can do that with mutate too. My point was to get a column like `humidity_count` in the screenshot. There are two `humidity_catog` <=65 and >65. So for 2006, I have only two counts. For temperature, I have three categories, so I should get only `three` counts for 2006 (each year).