# R Aggregation Error: count distinct

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm relatively new to R, so forgive me if this seems like a dumb question. I've started to run out of ideas from other examples on how to make this work, and I was hoping someone could help guide me in the right direction to get it working.

So I'm attempting to do a count distinct on SITE_ID to CLNCL_TRIAL_ID.

My data is actually in a dataframe (data2), but this is kind of what it looks like:

```
CLNCL_TRIAL_ID:
89794,
89794,
8613,
8613

SITE_ID:
12456,
12456,
100341,
30807
```

The Idea that my end result would be like count of 89794=1 and 8613=2

Here's what I have so far:

```
z <- aggregate(data2$SITE_ID ~ data2$CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(SITE_ID) length(unique(data2$SITE_ID)))
```

and I've attempted some alternate forms

```
aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, sum(!duplicated(data$SITE_ID)))

  aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, nlevels(factor(data2$SITE_ID)))

  aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(SITE_ID) length(unique(data2$SITE_ID)))
```

I keep running into the problem that instead of grouping by trial_ID, it is counting for the whole table. so 89794=3 and 8613=3.

Does anyone have an idea how to correct this issue? I feel like i'm overlooking something silly.
Also, as a side note: I'm trying to keep this limited to the base package of R if at all possible. If it isn't possible, no biggie.

Comment: table() might help. see this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215154/count-unique-values-in-r

Answer (score 2):

A couple of methods:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID = c(89794, 89794,8613, 8613), SITE_ID = c(12456, 12456, 100341, 30807))
```

Base R - table:

```
table(df)
               SITE_ID
CLNCL_TRIAL_ID 12456 30807 100341
     8613      0     1      1
     89794     2     0      0
```

dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, SITE_ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

  CLNCL_TRIAL_ID SITE_ID count
1           8613   30807     1
2           8613  100341     1
3          89794   12456     2
```

**Update**

To count distinct, just use `unique` for base r, or `distinct` for dplyr:

```
table(unique(df))
## to group/summarise the results you can use rowSums()
rowSums(table(unique(df)))


df %>%
distinct %>%
group_by(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID) %>%
summarise(count = n())
```

or, more succintly using Marek's suggestion

```
df %>% distinct %>% count(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID)
```

Comment: I think I've missed the part of the question asking for `distinct' counts. will udpate

Comment: `group_by(x) %>% summarise(n=n())` could be replaced by `count(x)`, so `df %>% distinct %>% count(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID)`

Answer (score 1):

Using functions from `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
data2 %>%
     group_by(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID) %>%
     summarise(nd = n_distinct(SITE_ID))
```

Your original approach doesn't work cause you reference original data set in function. Each of following will work:

```
aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(x) sum(!duplicated(x)))
aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(x) nlevels(factor(x)))
```

Also:

```
aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, n_distinct)
```

if you wish to mix `base` and `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you very much Marek. You and tospig both helped quite a bit and I have it working now. As more of a curiousity/learning question. Would you guys happen to know why my original idea wasn't aggregating correctly?

Comment: @user3776991 Function passed to `aggregate` was computed on original data (you used `$` reference). Should be: `aggregate(SITE_ID ~ CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, data2, function(x) length(unique(x)))` and similar for your alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table)
df <- data.table(CLNCL_TRIAL_ID = c(89794, 89794,8613, 8613), 
    SITE_ID = c(12456, 12456, 100341, 30807))
df[,length(unique(SITE_ID)),by=CLNCL_TRIAL_ID]
```

Produces

```
   CLNCL_TRIAL_ID V1
1:          89794  1
2:           8613  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using the `fun.aggregate` argument of the `dcast` function (which you can find in the `reshape2` package).

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, CLNCL_TRIAL_ID ~ SITE_ID, length, margins = T)
Using SITE_ID as value column: use value.var to override.
  CLNCL_TRIAL_ID 12456 30807 100341 (all)
1           8613     0     1      1     2
2          89794     2     0      0     2
3          (all)     2     1      1     4
```

But if you do not want a cross table you can just use `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$CLNCL_TRIAL_ID, df$SITE_ID, length)
 12456  30807 100341 
     2      1      1
```