# how to find the number of occurrences a unique value appears in a list in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency, unique-values

I extracted data from sql in R. The data is in a list. I want to find the number of occurrences each value appears in a column of the list. How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to R.

```
    group_by(demo) %>%
         summarise(unique_value = n_distinct(column_name))
```

I tried doing this above and the output was:

```
    unique_value
            <int>
             5
```

So there are 5 unique values. How do I determine how many times each unique value appears in the column?

Comment: Use `count` i..e. `data %>% count(demo)`

Comment: Can you post sample data using something like the output from `dput()`?

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to include what your dataset looks like using `dput`.
To start, depending on your object I would convert `demo` to a data.table. Then you can use the following to get the frequency of each unique value for a specific col.

```
library(data.table)
demo = as.data.table(demo)
demo_n = demo[,.N, by = column_name]
```

Additionally, I'd recommend checking out this question: [Count number of occurences for each unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215154/count-number-of-occurences-for-each-unique-value?rq=1)